# How to remove a functions in global environment within an R function

Tags: r

I need a to be able to remove functions from the global environment within an R function

```
f <- function(){}
g <- function(){}

stopifnot(length(lsf.str()) == 3) # new function in env
rm(list = lsf.str()) # this works interactively, I need this behavior within a function 
stopifnot(length(lsf.str()) == 0)

clear_fns_from_env <- function() { # something like this
  env_functions <- c("f", "g")
  rm(list = env_functions, envir = globalenv())
}


f <- function(){}
g <- function(){}

stopifnot(length(lsf.str()) == 2) # 
clear_fns_from_env() # this does not remove the functions in the global env
stopifnot(length(lsf.str()) == 0) # I expected this to clear f and g
```

I tried changing the inputs to the `pos` and `envir` parameters in `rm()`. I would expect it to be able to clear the parent environment.

Comment: Works for me if you use `envir = .GlobalEnv` instead of `envir = globalenv()`

Comment: I suspect it would be better practice to put your functions into a package than to put them into the global environment if this sort of housekeeping has become necessary.

Comment: @JonSpring totally agree, the issue is devs accidentally hit `source` which causes the functions to be written to the global env. That has the effect of overwriting the namespace of the package. I need to load a large number of files written with `save.image()` and clean the sourced functions out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you *why* this makes a difference, but using `.GlobalEnv`  instead of `globalenv()` works:

```
clear_fns_from_env <- function() { # something like this
  env_functions <- c("f", "g")
  rm(list = env_functions, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```